# How does gas flow change with gas composition?

Tags: thermodynamics, flow, estimation, gas

How does gas composition affect gas flow rate with all other parameters being constant? I am trying to calculate the flow rate of raw biogas with 63% CH4 and 37% CO2 relative to purified biogas with 93% CH4 and 7% CO2. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you have flow data and physical properties (e.g., MW), you can use this link to compare the mass flow rates.  https://lenoxlaser.com/resources/calculators/orifice-calculator/

Comment: I dont see the relevance as the link pertains to calculating flow with defined orifices.

Comment: Choose an arbitrary orifice diameter.  Run the calculation for the first case.  Keep the orifice diameter and everything else except gas composition constant, and run the calculation for the second case.  Then compare the two answers.  If that doesn't meet your criteria for "all other parameters being constant", please be more specific in your question.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. It still does not tell me how to do it.  But it helped to notice the relationship of density and flow is the square root of the density ratio of the two gas mixes. 
I am trying to figure out the discrepancy between the gas meter, the gas composition change and the manufacturer's orifice flow rating. I am making BioNG from biogas and operating it on a NG stove. I want to know how much gas was consumed and how much CO2 was removed from the biogas so i need to measure the gas volume before and after CO2 removal. Until now the numbers have not added up.

Comment: It would be useful if you updated your original question with the information that you just posted.